# Show New Products

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation

I'm using this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" column_count="3" products_count="8" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

to display new products on category page. I have added the code in static block and call from category, but when I go to the category the layered navigation is not showing. Is it possible when in 2column-left presentation the navigation be shown for the new listed products.

Comment: mike??is it is working or not??

Comment: No it's not wrong, with this piece of code I have listed all new products, but layered navigation is not apearing

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the category has `is anchor` turned on in the backend. This will make the layered navigation bar appear. However the layered navigation will only work on products in that category. I think it will ignore products outputted from a static block.

Comment: I already have but nothing is changed the layred navigation is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Check your module's xml layout as well as layered navigation xml layout file  file for reference name where layered navigation is included if it is included in  so it will not be display on 2 column left category view page.

Comment: *If it is included in reference name=right it won't display